# Read an XML string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, readxml

I have a string of type `string xml = @"<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>mo</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><daily dayFrequency=""1"" /></repeat><windowEnd>2012-10-31T10:00:00Z</windowEnd></rule></recurrence>";`

I want to read `dayFrequency` value which is `1` here, is there a way i can directly read `dayFrequency` under the tag `daily` and likewise there are many such tags such as **a="1", b="King"** etc. so i want to read directly the value assigned to a variable.

Kindly help.

The below code i used which reads the repeat tag

```
string xml = @"<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>mo</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><daily dayFrequency=""1"" /></repeat><windowEnd>2012-10-31T10:00:00Z</windowEnd></rule></recurrence>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

// this would select all title elements
XmlNodeList titles = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("repeat");
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your code?

Comment: dayFrequency=""1"" is wrong. " needs encoding as &quot; if I recall correctly.

Comment: Why don't you use XLinq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XElement.Parse(xml).Descendants("daily")
                   .Single()
                   .Attribute("dayFrequency")
                   .Value;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var val = xmlDoc.Descendants("daily")
                .Attributes("dayFrequency")
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Here val will be:

```
val = {dayFrequency="1"}
```

`val.Value` will give you `1`

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>mo</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><daily dayFrequency=""1"" /></repeat><windowEnd>2012-10-31T10:00:00Z</windowEnd></rule></recurrence>");
        string result = xdoc
            .Descendants("recurrence")
            .Descendants("rule")
            .Descendants("repeat")
            .Descendants("daily")
            .Attributes("dayFrequency")
            .First()
            .Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use getattribute().

For more info see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(path);

    foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//repeat").Value);
    }
```